# IntelliJ IDEA: generate JAR with specific classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

From an IDEA project I need to generate multiple JAR files, each JAR containing a subset of classes from the project. For each JAR I need to specify which compiled classes should be packaged into that JAR. What is the best way to do this?

Formerly I was using JDeveloper. I could add several deployment profiles, and in the deployment profile settings there was a tree view of all compiled classes, where I could set checkboxes to specify required classes. That was very handy. Is there a way to do the same in IDEA?

Apparently I need to use a "build systems" such as Ant, Maven, Gradle and so on. IDEA has integration plugins for these systems. Does any integration provide something like JDeveloper checkbox tree?

Comment: You need to create an artifact, like described here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/output-layout-tab.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#package

Comment: Does the artifact options window allow selecting individual classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) are build tools: they help you build your project (compile sources, automatically download libraries that you use, automatically run unit tests, etc).

These tools are de-facto standard tools in the Java world (almost everybody uses them). It is definitely recommended to use one of these tools to build your project instead of relying on your IDE.

I would not use Ant, it's old and should not be used for new projects anymore. Use either Maven or Gradle.

These tools do not provide nice graphical user inerfaces by themselves to configure the build. Instead, you write a configuration file (`pom.xml` in the case of Maven, `build.gradle` in the case of Gradle) that specifies what your project looks like and how it should be built.

You can then build your project on the command line, or let your IDE run Maven or Gradle to build the project. IntelliJ has good support for all of these build tools (for example, IntelliJ can read the build file and automatically set up an IntelliJ project).

One of the major advantages of using a build tool is that you are not dependent on a particular IDE anymore to build the project, and that you can let continuous integration tools such as Jenkins or Bamboo build the project automatically.

Comment: Since no one hinted at a GUI answer, apparently it's true. I have experimented a bit with Gradle and found that, instead of linking a Gradle project to an IDEA project, it's better to create an empty Gradle project, open it in IDEA and make all adjustments in the `build.gradle` file. Though, it's frustrating that a modern IDE doesn't have a user-friendly way of doing things which were so conveniently available fifteen years ago.